# Issues rendering MathJax using Sphinx due to HTML-CSS renderer

Tags: python, python-sphinx, mathjax, autodoc

I just upgraded to the following:

```sh
Sphinx==1.8.5
nbconvert==5.4.1
pandoc==1.0.2
```

I have always been able to render math in docs via a jupyter notebook using Sphinx (the way it is done for `seaborn`). However, after upgrading, the math no longer renders! If I right click where the equation should be, I can change the math renderer to either "svg" or "CommonHTML" and everything is fine - it just doesn't render with the default "HTML-CSS" math renderer for whatever reason. My question is: how can I change the default renderer in my config file?

What I tried:

`conf.py`

```py
...
extensions = [
    ...
    'sphinx.ext.mathjax'
    ...
]
...

mathjax_config = {
    'jax': ['input/TeX', 'output/CommonHTML']
}
```

However, this didn't change the default renderer like I thought it should. Does anyone know how to change the default renderer for MathJax within Sphinx?

Here is a gif:

[image]

Also, it would appear that `MathJax` is being loaded from CDN with a preferred config:

[image]

Comment: The settings in the MathJax contextual menu override the ones in your file, so if you used the menu to experiment with different renderers, then those settings may still be in effect.  Try removing the cookie for local files (since you are using a `file://` URL).  If that's not it, check to see if MathJax.js is being loaded with a `?config=` parameter, as those load specific input and output renderers, and your `jax` configuration won't be used.  Either of those could be the problem.

Comment: Hmm, they do appear to be loading with a config param (image added above). What's the easiest way to force `MathJax` to use the params in the sphinx-config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how `MathJax` worked for you before, but based on the [Sphinx-documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.8/usage/extensions/math.html) `MathJax` is not included in `Sphinx` by default. You have to specify the `mathjax_path` in your `conf.py` either using a local version or a server hosted one from [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/) for example.

Comment: Hmm..it does look like `MathJax` is being included from the CDN by default - it shows up in the network tab of chrome developer - it seems to load fine initially, and then hides all the math for whatever reason....

Comment: I see, does the issue happen only on Chrome or on other browsers too? I had a similar issue with Sphinx but it was only on Firefox.

Comment: Good question - safari doesn't seem to be working on my MBP, but here is a link: https://dhhagan.github.io/opcsim/tutorial/distribution.html

Answer (score 1):

While I wasn't able to get the `mathjax_config` approach to work, I was able to set the `mathjax_path` to a specific output processor, still through the CDN, which worked using CommonHTML.

So, an answer that works is to edit the `conf.py` file to include a line with:

```py
...
mathjax_path = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"
...
```

Comment: This is almost the same as my answer, an edit to mine would have been sufficient.